# Cannot ssh into EC2 instance from Windows using Putty

Tags: windows, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh

I was using a Mac to ssh into my ec2 instance, I am now using a Windows laptop and I cannot connect to the ec2 instance, any recommendations? I have followed the instructions using Putty but it still does not connect. I have even tried using MobaXterm to ssh into my a Ubuntu machine and then ssh from there and that still does not work either. I receive timeout errors in both cases. I have also checked the VPC and Subnets and everything in the route table is connected to each other how it should be. The Mac connection still works but I am just having trouble connecting through the Windows machine (using Putty).

Comment: Any chance that your EC2 instance security group has an ingress whitelist for your Mac IP but not your Windows IP (if they're different)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a helpful walk through guide: https://www2.linuxacademy.com/howtoguides/17385-use-putty-to-access-ec2-linux-instances-via-ssh-from-windows/

- Ensure that you transform the .pem to a .ppk file using PuttyGen found here: https://www.ssh.com/ssh/putty/windows/puttygen#sec-PuTTYgen-download-and-install
- Note: the user you login as by default one of the following:

•For an Amazon Linux AMI, the user name is ec2-user.

•For a RHEL AMI, the user name is ec2-user or root.

•For an Ubuntu AMI, the user name is ubuntu or root.

•For a Centos AMI, the user name is centos.

•For a Fedora AMI, the user name is ec2-user.

•For SUSE, the user name is ec2-user or root.

•Otherwise, if ec2-user and root don’t work, check with the AMI provider.

- Open Putty and add your the username@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (replace with your ec2's IP) to the host section
- use port 22
- Click the 'Auth' section on the right panel and select your .ppk file
- Go back to the 'Session' section and click 'open'

Answer (score 0):

1)you can use Mobaxterm or GitBash
2)gitbash is most recommended .
3) its easy to install and easy to work with.
4) follow this link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-3KjGtvU-E
5) and you are good to go connecting ec2 instance in your windows